# How to intelligently degrade or smooth GIS data (simplifying polygons)?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, gis, postgis

I have detailed US county maps, from the [TIGER LINE](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/) data sets. How might I sample, smooth, or degrade the data so that I get straighter, more boxy, less "noisy" shapes to represent the geographical features -- in this case just county boundaries and state lines, but maybe also in the general case?

The sampling could happen at rendering time if that can be done efficiently, or a parallel data set could be generated and stored. I am using [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/), and the lines are multi-polylines generated by `shp2pgsql` -- but any solution where you take a squiggly line and reduce it to a smoother line of roughly the same significance to a human interpreter would be very useful.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem with simply throwing away points is that you can quickly distort the shape of the original polygon. A better approach is to come at it from the other direction; start with a basic approximation of the polygon and then refine it upwards towards your complex shape.

An excellent example of this approach is the [Douglas-Puecker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm). You start with two vertices drawn from the full polygon. Add a third vertex by selecting the one that lies farthest from an edge drawn between the first two vertices. Continue adding points until you have something that sufficiently resembles your original polygon.

Answer (score 65):

Douglas-Peucker is definitely the right approach.  There are some simple ways to access implementations of it in PostGIS and QGIS that I thought I would add here for those who come across this post with a similar question.  The goal is to start with something like this:

[image]

and end up with something like this:

[image]

In PostGIS Douglas-Peucker is implemented as `simplify`, the syntax, detailed [here at bostongis.org](http://bostongis.org/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_simplify), is some variant of:

`SELECT transform(simplify(transform(the_geom, 2249), 500),4326) from the_geo_table`

This worked very well even on the full national dataset, with some few errors that seem due to bad underlying data.  It also turns out that in QGIS the menu item `Tools > Geometry Tools > Simplify Geometries` will export a simplified shapefile of any geometry and add it as a layer to your current project.

This is a pretty fundamental tool-set and I asked the question at too low a level, though it was nice to learn the underlying math, there is a good explanation of that [here: http://www.mappinghacks.com/code/PolyLineReduction/](http://www.mappinghacks.com/code/PolyLineReduction/), along with sample code that turns out not to be too necessary!

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to do this while maintaining common edges with Other polygons? e.g. simplified countries in europe, with common borders.

Comment: other polygon generalizing options with QGIS at [How to smooth/generalize a polygon in qgis](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/how-to-smooth-generalize-a-polygon-in-qgis) on sister GIS-SE site.

Comment: cool, but howto handle multiple polygons when they are next to each other? like when you have shapes of different zip code areas?

Comment: In QGIS 2.14.1-Essen: Processing > Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Simplify geometries

Comment: Just for a newer version of PostGIS function simplify changed the name to st_simplify. Same with transform.

Comment: Use ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology instead. It uses the same algorithm as ST_Simplify (Douglas-Pecker), but is guaranteed not to produce invalid geometries.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of QGIS, I suggest using ogr2ogr because it [does not delete polygons](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/4189)!

```
ogr2ogr output.shp input.shp -simplify 0.0001
```

Comment: Are the units of simplify the units of the projection?  For example perhaps those are lat or long degrees?

Comment: It seems the units are indeed the units used for the coordinates in the file.

Comment: Use ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology instead. It uses the same algorithm as ST_Simplify (Douglas-Pecker), but is guaranteed not to produce invalid geometries.

Comment: hey I realize this is OLD but your link is dead -- I'm actually trying to solve the problem of my reference dataset being way too precise

Comment: @jcollum I updated the link after some quick web searches

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple iterative smoothing algorithm:

for each three sequential points on any path, if the middle point has no intersections and is within some small threshold angle of the direct path between the two outer points, remove it.

Repeat until satisfied.

Answer (score 8):

You could also try Visvalingam’s algorithm, which iteratively removes the least perceptible part of a line. Here is a great explanation of that algorithm:

- http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [Simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/) which uses a combination of [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm) and Radial Distance algorithms. There are also links to many ports to other languages listed on the [github project](https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js)

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @unmounted is correct, but I would like to add one more suggestion.

Always use function ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology instead of ST_Simplify in PostGIS. Both use the same underlying algorithm (Douglas-Peucker), but the former avoids any simplifications which would result in invalid geometries. For example, ST_Simplify may result in geometry which intersects itself.